# Shadow volume front/light cap appearing in stencil buffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, shadow

I'm trying to implement shadow volumes according to [NVDIA GPU Gems Chapter 9. Efficient Shadow Volume Rendering](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch09.html) on iPad, but I'm having issues with the front / light cap appearing in my stencil buffer.

I'm trying to render shadows on the box in the middle of the picture below.  Shadows are being correctly generated on the right side of the box, but when I move the camera around, parts of the lit sides of the box are shadowed.  It seems to me like it could be a problem with the resolution of the depth buffer, not recognizing when the shadow volume is the same depth as the box and should not be drawn, but I've used `glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)` for the drawing of the shadow volumes to try to correct this, it doesn't seem to change anything.

[image]

Here is a summary of my code:

```
glClearStencil(0);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

[self drawAmbient];

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xff);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);

glStencilOpSeparate(GL_FRONT, GL_KEEP, GL_DECR_WRAP_OES, GL_KEEP);
glStencilOpSeparate(GL_BACK, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR_WRAP_OES, GL_KEEP);

glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

[self drawShadowVolumes];

glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0, 0xff);
glStencilOpSeparate(GL_FRONT, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
glStencilOpSeparate(GL_BACK, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL);
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

[self drawDirectionalLight];
```

Answer (score 0):

You doing something wrong. For default Z-fail technic you must have 2 passes of shadow volume rendering, one for "Degenerated quads" (shadow volumes) and one for "Exactly object geometry" with flats normals (shadow caps). I can see only one pass for "Degenerated quads", but where pass for "Exactly geometry" with opposed flags in stencil buffer?

Degenerated quads must be rendered with

glStencilOpSeparate(GL_FRONT, GL_KEEP, GL_DECR_WRAP_OES, GL_KEEP);
glStencilOpSeparate(GL_BACK, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR_WRAP_OES, GL_KEEP);

and Exactly geometry must be rendered with opposed flags

glStencilOpSeparate(GL_FRONT, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR_WRAP_OES, GL_KEEP);
glStencilOpSeparate(GL_BACK, GL_KEEP, GL_DECR_WRAP_OES, GL_KEEP);

The depth test must be GL_LESS or GL_LEQUAL like in simple geometry rendering.